# How to restore app data from Google Drive Android SDK without user interaction like WhatsApp

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am working on an Android App which requires saving certain key-value data into Cloud. So when the user installs my app, I could restore the key-value data from Cloud. I have done a lot of research including Android BackupAgent API which is not stable at all. I have done certain research about using Google Drive Android SDK, which indeed could backup and restore the key-value data successfully.  But it requires user interaction to select which account, even though my device only adds one Google Account and it has been authorized the app to access Google Drive SDK before.

I would like to make the whole process, backup and restore, as seamless and automatically as possible, with limited user interaction. I noticed that WhatsApp Android could implement such feature. But I failed in finding samples in Google Drive SDK [samples](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos).

Is there any sample that demonstrates the data restoration automatically without selecting the Google Account like WhatsApp Android? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sample that you provided is the best sample of Google Drive Android API demos that you will find in the internet. This demo will help you on how to work with the app data that you want. Like you said, you already checked the Backup API and it seems that it isn't applicable in your situation. Did you already check this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/07/auto-backup-for-apps-made-simple.html) that provides improvement from the previous API?

Comment: Yes, I have been aware of that link. But it only works on API 23 or above, which is not an option for our project.  : (